# CSS overriding by several files

Tags: html, css

I am sorry beforehand if question is stupid, but this is my first project.

I got html.css layouts from HTML/CSS-coder, and for each view they made separate html and separate CSS file.

But I am developing SPA, so there will be one page as an entry-point. Obviously, it should contain all CSS files for all views. The problem is that some of the CSS files contain classes with the same name, but different content. So if I just put list of CSS files in the entry html, some views become a mess, because they use wrong classes.

Thanks a lot.

As I see that my question is not being understood, I decided to give example:

File1.css, used in view1:

```
.class1 {
cursor: default;
}
```

File2.css, used in view2:

```
.class1 {
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Obviously, I need both as is and cannot use `!important;` as this will make a browser to use only one of them in both view1 and view2.

What is correct approach to solve this? Ask html coder to re-name classes, or do it myself? Or is there some tool that can somehow consolidate CSS files automatically?

Also, how usually html/css layouts should be coded for SPA to avoid this situation?

---

**UPDATE 1**
I appreciate efforts the SO community made to help me though question is indeed could seem vague. I've already learned a lot from all answers.
The situation is much clearer for me now.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: @Paulie_D Please check, added some details. Even if question is broad, I still need some fulcrum to solve it, as now I have no idea at all. Thanks

Comment: How are you handling the different views? As in, the developer gave you different CSS files presumably because they are effectively for separate "pages" there must be some event or segregation that causes the Application to switch from view 1 to view 2

Comment: In all honesty it sounds like a mess. I'd scrap the CSS given and start afresh yourself. You want to avoid using `!important` as your CSS should cascade and ideally be modular. It sounds like you've been given some less than desirable code to work with!

Comment: @IStanley I use ReactJS and React-router. So it does something like history.push("url") on click, and new view is rendered by front-end, without going to server. Is it what you're asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it seems as though you need to use parent / child selectors depending on which view it is:

**file1.css:**

```
.view1 .class1 {
  // Styles
}
```

**file2.css:**

```
.view2 .class1 {
  // Styles
}
```

To achieve this, look at each view and see if there's a top-level element you can append a class to, such as the `<body>` tag:

```
<body class="view1">
    <div class="class1">
```

AND

```
<body class="view2">
    <div class="class1">
```

This removes any need for `!important` (stay away from that as much as you can!)

Comment: I accept it as your answer was the first amongst alike, and seems to be fast solution for the situation, to avoid scrapping all that is already done and starting afresh. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The problem in many projects such as yours is that developers do Not do what they are supposed to be doing in standard manner.  The correct approach to manage CSS Files in more than 500 lines of CSS Code is to follow Modular, Structured Patterns such as BEM. These Standards guid you through the right choice for the naming conventions and writing Css Components.
For example in [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) they use components and utilities to manage large projects and avoid such collisions.

#### Your way to get out of it

1. You have always the chance to write your styles inline inside the html code. This would bring a high specificity and will override Clas Based CSS of the files included.
2. You could provide a `.css` file of your own and include it after all that developre's css and `!important` all the mess or with the help of high specificity like `id`s make your CSS win!
3. Forget about the whole CSS They provided you and start using a framework like `Twitter Bootstrap` or `Zurb Foundation`.

Comment: Thanks for giving the direction. It seems for now the correct way to develop frontend is to have html/css coding process in the same hands as the whole  JS interface development. Will look to BEM and other mentioned topics.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you are going to have to go in by hand and re-code the classes. Additionally You can add id's or an extra class to whatever section you are currently styling.

**For example:** `<div class="CSS-coder" id="myExtraStyles">` **or** `<div class="CSS-coder myExtraStyles">`

*!important* **will** override most styles. But it would  be better to edit the current classes that wont be sharing style attributes.

Additionally remember that "Cascading" means from top to bottom. So any styles loaded after the default styles will override the styles loaded before it.

I agree with the other poster in that a "framework" is the way to go.

Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 2):

#### EDIT

Re-reading your question I think I have a better idea now as to what your actual problem is.

What you can do is to find or add a parent element that you can use to filter out the styles.

Let's say you link to those 2 CSS files and both of them define a style like so:

```
/* First CSS file */
.sub-div {
    background-color: red;
}

/* Second CSS file */
.sub-div {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

On your HTML, look for a parent element that you can use.

```
<div class='red-only'>
    <div class="sub-div"><p>View 1</p></div>
</div>

<div class='blue-only'>
    <div class="sub-div"><p>View 2</p></div>
</div>
```

Create a custom CSS (you should link to the file last).

```
.blue-only .sub-div {
    background-color: blue;
}

.red-only .sub-div {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: A little bit harsh that this is being downvoted given that the "can't use !important" was added after you answered, but you might want to edit/delete this!

Comment: I did not downvote, but in general it is best to avoid using `!important` when possible. Instead, one should use a dominant selector, such as `table.class1 > tr > td` to override `table > tr > td`.

Comment: @IStanley I don't really care about those numbers about reputations. I'm just here to try and help.

Answer (score 0):

When working with css, the order is important.

The file that is declared last will have the highest precedence.Now with that in mind if you have

```
<link href="file1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="file2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Then the code specified in file2 will override the code in file1, only if they have the same specificity. Meaning that the more specific declaration will trump even if it is declared in file1. So if you want to override a rule in file1 you will need the exact same declaration in file2.

When working with files created by others like bootstrap or similar it is preferable to create a new file.

```
<link href="file1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="file2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="myStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

This will help you avoid trouble that might arise from modifying the originals.

The code inspector in chrome and firefox will be helpful when you need to check wich classes are applied to a certain element.

It might be that your element is applying a class that overrides the one you are trying to apply to the element. For example:

```
<div class="class1 class2 class3" ></div>
```

Class3 might override parts of class1 and class2, because it is the class applied last. Like i said, in CSS order is very important.

Do not use !important if possible. You might want to override values later on, and with !important will become difficult to do so. Verify if there are !important declarations in file1, because these might be the ones causing you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a programming language? Or just CSS/HTML markup? If you use a programming language (what I suppose, as you got one entry point) you could simply make a big switch statement, check the current view and then inject accordingly the appropriate css file.